# XPath: Select self and following sibling together

Tags: html, xpath

```
<div>
    <dt>
        Test 1
    </dt>
    <dd>
    </dd>
    <dt>
        Test 2
    </dt>
    <dd>
    </dd>
</div>
```

I have this XPath written so far

```
//dt[contains(text(), "Test")]/self::dt|following-sibling::dd
```

But this is not bringing both **dt** and **dd** but just **dt**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it must be a single XPath 1.0 expression then you'll have to say

```
//dt[contains(., 'Test')] | //dt[contains(., 'Test')]/following-sibling::dd[1]
```

The final `[1]` is important, as without that it would extract *all* dd elements that follow a dt containing "Test", i.e. given

```
<div>
    <dt>
        Test 1
    </dt>
    <dd>
        Foo
    </dd>
    <dt>
        Something else 2
    </dt>
    <dd>
        Bar
    </dd>
</div>
```

the version without the `[1]` would match three nodes, the `dt` containing "Test 1" and *both* the "Foo" and "Bar" `dd` elements.  *With* the `[1]` you would correctly get only "Test 1" and "Foo".

But depending on exactly how you're using the XPath it may be clearer to first select

```
//dt[contains(., 'Test')]
```

and then iterate over the nodes that this matches, and evaluate

```
. | following-sibling::dd[1]
```

in the context of each of those nodes in turn.

Answer (score 4):

When using XPath 2.0:

```
//dt[contains(text(), "Test")]/(self::dt, following-sibling::dd)
```

Comment: that's very neat. but I am using 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPATH:

```
//dt[contains(text(), "Test")]/self::dt or //dt[contains(text(), "Test")]/following-sibling::dd
```

Comment: That's what I alternatively used but this is long :)

Comment: if you are using "1.0", this is the only option

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicating the `contains` test for the `dt` element, you can rewrite your query so all desired output elements are expressed within the search criterion only once:

```
//*[contains(self::dt|self::dd/preceding-sibling::dt[1],"Test")]
```

**Explanation:** start with the pool of all possible output elements, and of those, choose a either `dt` or a `dd` preceded by a `dt`, where either `dt` matches the search.

Included this answer to show a way that reduces code duplication and makes it easier to read the expression's union operator `|`...

Answer (score -1):

According to your example, you might be able to use this xpath, it's shorter and simpler, but it's under the assumption that you're looking for dt, and then you want ALL siblings of dt (not just the following sibling and self). This xpath looks for dt's parent and grabs all its children:

```
//dt[contains(text(), "Test")]/../*
```