# XPath group selected node with next sibling

Tags: java, xpath, saxon

I use `"net.sf.saxon" % "Saxon-HE" % "9.9.1-6"` and i'm trying to group some nodes of a HTML Site with XPath.

#### HTML Page

```
    <div class="item-list">
        <div class="row-title"><h3>Item 1</h3></div>
        <div class="row-body"><div>nested stuff for Item 1</div></div>
    
        <div class="row-title"><h3>Item 2</h3></div>
        <div class="row-body"><div>nested stuff for Item 2</div></div>
    
        <div class="row-title"><h3>Item 3</h3></div>
        <div class="row-body"><div>nested stuff for Item 3</div></div>
    </div>
```

#### Expected result (array)

```
 1. <div class="row-title"><h3>Item 1</h3></div><div class="row-body"><div>nested stuff for Item 1</div></div>
 2. <div class="row-title"><h3>Item 2</h3></div><div class="row-body"><div>nested stuff for Item 2</div></div>
 3. <div class="row-title"><h3>Item 3</h3></div><div class="row-body"><div>nested stuff for Item 3</div></div>
```

This is one of my tries/attempts.

```
//div[contains(@class, 'item-list')]/div[contains(@class, 'row-body') or contains(@class, 'row-title')]
```

But the result (see below) ist not as expected.
(I need the results e.g. **1.** and **2.** together.)

```
1. <div class="row-title"><h3>Item 1</h3></div>
2. <div class="row-body"><div>nested stuff for Item 1</div></div>
3. <div class="row-title"><h3>Item 2</h3></div>
4. <div class="row-body"><div>nested stuff for Item 2</div></div>
5. <div class="row-title"><h3>Item 3</h3></div>
6. <div class="row-body"><div>nested stuff for Item 3</div></div>
```

I also tried something with "following-sibling", but unfortunately without success.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you considered using the xpath 'or' operator to union the results?

Comment: ```//div[@class='item-list']/div```

Comment: Yes, but both gives me another result (not the expected). (I have updated my question).

Comment: I found similar questions e.g. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584045/xpath-select-self-and-following-sibling-together. But they search only one specific result and i want all result in groups.